# How to perform a MYSQL join on two tables where the condition for the value of the foreign key to the second table could also be null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains two foreign keys. I need to be able to query that table and perform joins to bring in the data from the other tables. The problem I have is that the second foreign key, well, I've set it to be nullable.

My table kinda looks like this...

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    fk_meal INT NOT NULL, -- Foreign key to meals table
    fk_drink INT NULL -- Foreign key to drinks table
);
```

An order could be placed with or without a drink. A meal is mandatory but a drink isn't. I'd like to be able to pull data from the database even when `fk_drink` is NULL.
The way I'm try to do that is via the following query...

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
INNER JOIN meals ON meals.id = orders.fk_meal 
LEFT JOIN drinks ON (drinks.id = orders.fk_drink OR orders.fk_drink = NULL)
```

The query fires okay and I get data back but when `fk_drink` is NULL, I get an object containing ONLY the id. When `fk_drink` actually contains a drink I get back all data perfectly.

Is there a way I could get back all the other data and NULL for `fk_drink` when there are no drinks or is there some better way I could handle this?
Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check `orders.fk_drink = NULL` is incorrect, and it should be:

```
orders.fk_drink IS NULL
```

However, this check is not even necessary, and you should be using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN meals m
    ON m.id = o.fk_meal
LEFT JOIN drinks d
    ON d.id = o.fk_drink;
```

Going back to your original code `orders.fk_drink = NULL`, the problem with comparing `fk_drink` to `NULL` directly using the `=` operator is that this comparison is itself unknown.  This means that you may not be capturing the records which fail the left join correctly.

Comment: Changing orders.fk_drink = NULL to orders.fk_drink IS NULL, returns the same result. For the fk_drinks that are null I get back an object with only the id. Changing my query to match yours returns the same result as before.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.  We can't return data that isn't really there.

Comment: I was oversimplifying the table. I've just now created a new database with those test tables and tested out your query and it works. The problem now seems to be on my end. Let me if I can find the issue. Thank you.